Ограничить количество итераций цикла в python
Делаю проверку сайта с курсами и нужно проверять пользовательский код. Сделал сервер для принятия и выполнения кода от пользователей и обернул его в докер контейнер. Вопрос в следующем: если на сервер придет бесконечный цикл (например, while True: 1+1), как я могу установить количество итераций, после которого будет вылезать исключение?
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from loguru import logger
import tempfile
import subprocess
from os.path import abspath
from os import remove

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/exec', methods=['POST'])
def execute_task():    
    request_data = request.get_json()
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as stdin:
        code_file = open(request_data["uid"], "w")
        valid_src = code_validate(request_data["src"])
        code_file.write(valid_src)
        code_file.close()
        data = "\n".join(list(map(str, request_data["input"])))
        logger.debug(data)
        stdin.write(bytes(data, encoding='utf8'))
        stdin.seek(0)
        try:
            p = subprocess.run(
                        ["python", abspath(code_file.name)],
                        stdin=stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        encoding='utf-8',
                        universal_newlines=True,
                        timeout=15
                    )
            output = p.stdout
            remove(abspath(code_file.name))
        except Exception as error:
            remove(abspath(code_file.name))
            if type(error) == subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
                output = "Time Out"
            else:
                raise error
            
        logger.debug(output)
        
        resoult = {
            "input" : request_data["input"],
            "output" : output
        }
        return jsonify(resoult)

def code_validate(src):
    match = re.search(r"^import (?!math)\S+", src)
    if match:
        src = "raise Exception('Illegal import')"
    return src

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)


По таймеру? ‍♀️

Итерации чего имеются в виду, где цикл? Вообще, конечно, затея выполнять произвольный код, который засылают - ну, такое ))

@Amgarak можно и по таймеру, например если цикл крутится больше 20 секунд, то ошибка

@CrazyElf , Добавил уточнение в вопрос.  например, while True: 1+1. По поводу безопасности я понимаю на что иду. Поэтому пытаюсь как можно больше урезать функционал, чтобы были только необходимые базовые инструменты

В функции есть параметр timeout. Возможно это поможет в решении этой проблемы.
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None, **other_popen_kwargs)
Subprocess
